# How to add new extention to stevedore ExtensionManager

Tags: python

I'm really confused about how stevedore ExtensionManager works!? and how can I add a new plugin to its available options? I know where current plugins are and where they have been introduced (in setup.py). What I don't understand is that totally how it helps?
Actually, I'm looking for a way to add a new backend to `edx-proctoring` backends. They use [this method](https://github.com/edx/edx-proctoring/blob/9f0fc5ec67a2d6beb5584e633b01dfe7927f8930/edx_proctoring/apps.py#L112) to load extensions. and I want to know that should I create a new fork from the repository, extend it with my codes, and add the plugins name as a new entry point? Or it is possible to add a snippet to the main `edx-platform` codebase or maybe somewhere else, and then somehow make it accessible by the `edx-proctoring` module.

For those who are unfamiliar with edX:
**edx-platform**: is an open-source LMS. [link](https://open.edx.org/)
**edx-proctoring**: is a module that edx-platform uses to perform proctoring over exams. [link](https://github.com/edx/edx-proctoring)
**backends**: here are plugins to make communication between the LMS and the proctoring software

Answer (score 0):

According to this document: [Adding Plugins in Other Packages](https://docs.openstack.org/stevedore/latest/user/tutorial/creating_plugins.html#adding-plugins-in-other-packages)

> Part of the appeal of using entry points for plugins is that they can be distributed independently of an application.

Therefore it is possible to develop a plugin for an application, inside another application.

> It is common to use a plugin namespace prefixed with the name of the application or library that loads the plugins, to ensure it is unique, but that name has no bearing on what Python package the code for the plugin should live in.

Easily set the proper entry point for your package, and setuptools will find and register it for you.

Check the document and you'll see an example with more explanations.

Comment: note: it isn't tested yet. I found it just a couple of minutes ago.